# Can't view pdf file inside container - RenderConstrainedOverflowBox error

Tags: flutter, pdf, containers

i'm trying to visualize a pdf file inside a container coming from StreamBuilder,
always getting the following error: `RenderConstrainedOverflowBox object was given an infinite size during layout.`

I have tried wrapping the listView inside an Expanded widget but still getting a different error, tried to fix container height as well but still getting the error.

here is my code:

```
class MyFile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFile({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFile> createState() => _MyFileState();
}

class _MyFileState extends State<MyFile> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  PdfViewerController? pdfViewerController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 150,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('cartesP')
                  .where('userId', isEqualTo: user!.uid)
                  .limit(1)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                        return SfPdfViewer.network(
                          x['fileUrl'],
                          controller: pdfViewerController,
                        );
                      });
                }
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also tried different solutions from threads on stack overflow but none of them worked for me! I'd be grateful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `ListView` using `SingleChildScrollView`. Because `ListView` itself can scroll.

You can try setting height for ListView child.

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
  return Container(
    height: 150,
    child: SfPdfViewer.network(
            x['fileUrl'],
            controller: pdfViewerController,
          ),
      );
});
```